# Turkish Character Problems

Tags: beamer, unicode, turkish

The code below works but Turkish characters do not appear. I tried adding

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
```

but this time the code does not work. Any idea why?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{warsaw}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

 \title{Valuing Health}
 \author[Günal Bilek]{Günal Bilek}
 \institute{University of X}

\setcounter{page}{51}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]
\titlepage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{balance.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, not `latin1`

Comment: @egreg Next one?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your file is saved as UTF-8 and add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, not `latin1`.

I also simplified the list of packages, removing duplicates and those that are already loaded by `beamer`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib} 

\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

 \title{Valuing Health}
 \author[Günal Bilek]{Günal Bilek}
 \institute{University of X}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]
\titlepage
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I bet you already hit rep cap today. Upvoted anyway :-)